# Not able to boot Ubuntu Karmic Koala

Tags: ubuntu

I took the ISO image of Ubuntu 9.10 release candidate and did a CD burn. I installed it on a WinXP Home system (Wubi). For the first two weeks both the OSs were working fine. But now the Ubuntu boot is not working. I don't know how to fix it up. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The error message might be helpful...

Comment: Define "not working".  More info, what's happening, what's not happening, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason for WUBI installs not working is if Windows XP doesn't close down correctly then the NTFS partition will be marked as unclean. Try booting into Windows opening a command prompt

```
Start -> Run -> cmd.exe
```

then do this command

```
chkdsk c: /f
```

It should ask you this question

```
Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Would you like to schedule this volume to be
checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N)
```

Accept that (Y). Reboot into Windows and let chkdsk finish then reboot into Linux. If this doesn't work then you have a real problem.